# Make 2d sprite move in unity

Tags: unity, 2d, platform

At the moment I have a movement script which moves my player in Bothe directions but it only faces 1 way -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Jump();
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, 5f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
    
}
```

How can I make the sprite face the other way when I move west not east?

Comment: Presumably you considered using the `flipX` property of the `SpriteRenderer` component? Note that if you have a Rigidbody on an object, you should not move it by setting `transform.position`. All movement should be routed through the Rigidbody to ensure it plays nicely with physics.

Comment: Yeh it is glitchy but how do I move it with the rigid body then\

Comment: ...[did you try a search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+move+with+rigidbody2d+platformer&ia=web)? This is documented *very* extensively in Unity tutorials and past Q&A here. You'll make much faster progress if you try existing documented solutions first, rather than posting a question where you need to wait for someone to come along and re-type what's already at your fingertips out there on the web.